# Logarithmic Vertical and Horizontal Axes lines in MS Chart Control

Tags: c#, mschart

The image presents a logarithmic graph. I want to create a similar graph using MS Chart control. I know there is a way to convert normal graph to logarithmic graph but i am not able to create vertical and horizontal axes lines (light gray in color) similar to the graph below.

[image: Logarithmic graph with vertical and horizontal axes lines]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to set the chart's axes `IsLogarithmic` property to `true` and set up their `MinorGrid` as follows:

```
private static void SetupAxis(Axis axis)
{
    // Set the logarithmic scale mode:
    axis.IsLogarithmic = true;

    // Enable the minor grid lines:
    axis.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
    // Set the color of the minor grid lines:
    axis.MinorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gray;
    // Set the inverval to 1:
    axis.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;

    // Enable the major grid lines:
    axis.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
    // If not set, the major grid lines are defaulted to the black color
}
```

Usage:

```
ChartArea area = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

SetupAxis(area.AxisX);
SetupAxis(area.AxisY);
```